# Where can I get a "black screen" screensaver for OS X Lion?

Tags: mac, osx-lion, screensaver

Mac OS X Lion doesn't come with a "black screen" screensaver. Where can I get a screensaver that works with Lion and blanks the screen?

Comment: my bad. I can't unvote it (unless you change the answer), but I would. I was under the impression that you just asked this question with some no googling; but your question before the edit shows otherwise. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I uploaded this for you, you can [download the screen saver file here](http://cl.ly/2G2K0A352L161f3s0R2e).

If you want to do it manually, do it like this:

- Open *Quartz Composer.app*. This is no longer ships with Xcode by default. You need to install Xcode first and then download the [Graphics Tools for Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=graphics%20tools%20for%20xcode). Be sure to download the appropriate version. I copied the application files to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/` so they are listed under `Xcode->Open Developer Tool`.
- Create a new blank file with the Screensaver template. Delete everything except for the "Clear" panel. You can also start with a totally empty window and drag "Clear" from the Patch Library to the work area.

  [image]
- Save it under `/Users/your-user/Library/Screen Savers` to make it available for you only, or `/Library/Screen Savers` to make it available for all other users. Doing the latter, you'll have to enter an admin password.
- Then, select it in System Preferences under "Other".

[image]

And there you go, a simple black screensaver.

---

Alternatively, you could of course just put the monitor to sleep, or let it display a folder of pictures, which only has one black picture inside.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but I had to save 'blank_screen.qtz' it to my home directory then 'sudo cp ~/blank_screen.qtz /Libraray/Screen\ Savers/blank_screen.qtz' .. could you update your post plz.

Comment: You only have to do this if you want to make it available system-wide (notice the difference between `~/Library`, which is in your home folder, and `/Library`, which is for all users. The former should work — but I'll adapt it to clarify.

Comment: @lexu Interestingly, this one showed "Quartz Composer" after a while. I fixed it and hope this now works perfectly.

Comment: I'm curious why you wouldn't just put the monitor to sleep...why incur the extra wear and tear on your backlight, trivial though it may be?

Comment: @peelman I don't know — OP asked for it, I suggested to put the monitor to sleep anyway. Could be a problem with external display though (some take a while to get back from a display sleep or even switch to another input source).

Comment: my monitor takes for ever to go to sleep, until it does the changing screen is anoyingly distracting ... and it doesn't sleep at all, it seems,  with some screen savers - can the thing detect 'action' on the port?

Comment: I have 2 external monitors connected to MBP and putting the monitor to sleep is 1) very slow and 2) causes confusion when it wakes up - Cmd-Tab list of applications start being displayed on my secondary monitor which is very inconvenient. With "blank" screensaver I can nicely lock and unlock the screen with no slow wake up of all 3 monitors and no Cmd-Tab running away to another monitor. Thank you, slhck! And btw, it works with OSX 10.10.5.

Comment: Also works with OS X 10.11 El Capitan!

Comment: I've seen several hackintoshes that cannot hibernate or sleep, and if you switch the display off, you have to reboot to get it back online.

Answer (score 17):

Simple is best for me.

[image: Black Image]

Place this flat black image in a folder and set that folder as your screensaver source for the Classic screensaver style.

[image: Classic → Choose Folder]

Comment: I did the same, and while this is indeed simple, I found that my system gets ridiculously hot while the screen is locked, with the fan spinning at max speed.

Comment: Odd - you might need to look into activity monitor or ssh into the Mac to see why the CPU/GPU is pegged. Or you could just turn off the screen entirely - why waste cycles drawing a black background?

Comment: When the screen is off, the load goes away. But I cannot control how long it takes for the monitor to turn off; my system settings are somewhat locked down by corporate policy. I've decided to go with the accepted answer and "programmed" a blank screensaver.

Answer (score 2):

Just get [this](http://www.wurst-wasser.net/wiki/index.php?title=Software_Projects_Overview#Blank_Screen_Saver) one, it worked fine for me on 10.6 and now on 10.7:

> There it is, THE REAL screensaver. Since this screen saver will only
>   display a black blank screen it should actually save your screen. Of
>   course, if you REALLY want to save your screen use the "Energy saving"
>   settings in your system's preferences. Now featuring transparency!
>   It's Freeware, so don't hesitate to
>   [Media:Blankscreensaverfolder120.zip](http://www.wurst-wasser.net/wiki/images/4/48/Blankscreensaverfolder120.zip) download the 1.2.0 version (for
>   Snow Leopard).